# Safari can't open pages because server does not respond + problems with delayed response

Tags: macos, safari, tabs

For some time, I have been experiencing problems with Safari. I have faced these two issues:

1. When a tab is opened, and some page is loaded and I try to search for something through the search bar, the tab freezes for some time, and it opens what I asked for only after that.
2. Safari regularly says that it can't open a page, but after reloading the page, it opens the page successfully. This happens on all pages.

Does anyone else face similar issues? Can someone help?

My MacOS version is macOS Monterey 12.1.

Comment: Have you tested another browser to see if similar issues occur? Does the issue occur in different networks? If it only occurs on one network, are there other computers and are they facing any problems?

Comment: I tested Google Chrome, it works fine. The problem is persistent for a few networks.